# Определить id массива

Tags: jquery

Есть список с чекбоксами и массив вида `arr{id: i; person: name; state: notActive}`. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на определенный чекбокс `state: not` становился `state: active`.

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <div class="field">
      <label> <input type="checkbox">First</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="field">
      <label> <input type="checkbox">Second</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="field">
      <label> <input type="checkbox">Third</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="checkbox"> Выбрать всех
```

Comment: Легко. Но как Вы решили? Или Вы дали ТЗ и вперёд?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0hsaca1u/ забыл добавить свое решение

Comment: @Imp3l F12 - Console

Comment: @Igor проверял уже. не работает. если бы работало, то я бы не обратился сюда

Comment: Есть подозрение что Вы просто наспех каких-то строк накидали, чтобы показать что Вы что-то делали. Код мало того, что не работает, так ещё непонятно как должен работать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно перебрать все значения в массиве и у каждого поменять переменную

```js
var arr = [],
    $field = $('.field'),
    $field_input = $('.field input'),
    $all = $('#all');

// Создаём массив
$field.each(function(i) {
  $label = $(this).find('label');

  arr[i] = {id: i, person: $label.text(), state: false};
})

// Нажатие на input
$field_input.click(function() {
  var i = $field.index( $(this).parents('.field') );
  
  arr[i].state = this.checked ? true : false;
  
  console.log( arr );
});

// Нажатие на checkbox "все"
$all.click(function() {
  if( !this.checked ){
    // Отключаем везде checked
    $field.find('input').prop('checked', false);
    
    // Изменяем переменную во всех элементах массива
    $.each(arr, function() {
      this.state = false;
    });
  }else{
    // Включаем везде checked
    $field.find('input').prop('checked', true);
    
    // Изменяем переменную во всех элементах массива
    $.each(arr, function() {
      this.state = true;
    });
  };
  
  console.log( arr );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <div class="field">
      <label><input type="checkbox">First</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="field">
      <label><input type="checkbox">Second</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="field">
      <label><input type="checkbox">Third</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" id="all"> Выбрать всех
```